# Trying to select columns in R but it only assumes rows

Tags: r, variables, rows, selection

I am trying to select 41 variables from 827 existing ones. I am using the code:

```
`myvars <- c('newid',    # CU id
            'region',   # region
            'state',    # state
            'cutenure', # housing tenure 
            'fam_size',  # family size
            'no_earnr', # number of earners
            'num_auto', # number of vehicles owned
            'popsize',  # population size (see codes)
            'inclass',  # income class
            'age_ref',  # age reference person 
            'educ_ref', # education reference person (see codes)
            'ref_race', # race reference person (1=white, 2=black, 3= nat-am, 4=asian, 5=pac-isl, 6=multi-race)
            'inc_hrs1', # hours x week by ref person
            'inc_hrs2', # hours x week by spouse
            'incweek1', # number weeks worked ref person
            'incweek2', # number weeks worked spouse
            'fincbtax', # income before tax past 12 month
            'fincatax', # income after tax past 12 month
            'fsalaryx', # wage and salary income before ded.
            'totexppq', # tot exp prev quarter
            'totexpcq', # tot exp curr quarter
            'majapppq', # major appliances prev quarter
            'majappcq', # major appliances curr quarter
            'FOODHOME', # Expenditures food at home
            'FOODAWAY', # Food away from home
            'ALCBEV',   # Alcholic Beverages
            'OWNDWECQ', # Owned Dwellings
            'ZRENTDWL', # Rented Dwellings
            'OTHLODCQ', # Other Lodging
            'UTILCQ',   # Utilities
            'MISCEQPQ', # Household Equipment
            'HOUSOPCQ', # Household Operations
            'APPARCQ',  # Apparel and Services
            'VEHICLCQ', # Vehicle Expenditures
            'OTHVEHCQ', # Other Vehicle Expenditures
            'GASMOCQ',  # Gasoline
            'TRNOTHCQ', # Public Transportation
            'HEALTHCQ', # Health Care
            'ENTERTCQ', # Entertainment
            'PERSCACQ', # Personal Care
            'READCQ',   # Reading
            'EDUCACQ',  # Education
            'TOBACCCQ' # Tobacco
           )

newdataQ1 = dataQ1[,myvars]`
```

After this I received the error:

Error in `[.data.frame`(dataQ1, , myvars): undefined columns selected
Traceback:

1. dataQ1[, myvars]
2. `[.data.frame`(dataQ1, , myvars)
3. stop("undefined columns selected")

If I change the comma and put

newdataQ1 = dataQ1[myvars,]

It allows me to procede, but keeps 41 rows instead of 41 columns, keeping the original number of columns.

How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: What is dataQ1? Are you looking to create a dataframe?

Comment: Almost sure one or more of `myvars` don't exist in `dataQ1`. Check: `setNames(myvars %in% names(dataQ1), myvars)`.

Comment: your code works for me. What does your data frame look like? Can you post a minimal example of it, maybe the first 3 columns or so? Working example: `dataQ1 <- data.frame(newid=c(1,2,3), region=c(2,3,4), state=c(3,4,5))` then `myvars <- c("newid", "state")` then `dataQ1[,myvars]`

Comment: dataQ1 is data from the American Consumer Expenditure Survey, First quarter of 2018

Comment: Yes it's true, some variables do not exist. Which is a surprise because they are included in the dictionary provided by the American Bureau of Labor Statistics.

Thank you for the tip, going to check it!

Comment: @FranciscoTavares: did my answer below solve your problem? If yes, please accept the answer as a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe dplyr would be a good way for you to partition your data.
It's a great package that makes your request very easy and well readable
(I'm using pipe operators, they also make life much easier and the code more readable)

```
newdataQ1 <- dataQ1 %>% select(myvars)
```

It's worth checking out the tutorials of dplyr (e.g. on datacamp) to get familiar with the syntax.

If you want to use basic R only you need to specify that you want to select colnames:

```
newdataQ1 <- dataQ1[, colnames(dataQ1) %in% myvars]
```